# Python build package with dependencies included

Tags: python-2.7, build-process, setuptools

What is the best way to include dependencies into the build?
I use numpy, pandas, graphlab in my code.

Is there a way to do this with setuptools ?

Answer (score 0):

I've enjoyed using [PyInstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller) for this purpose.

Numpy, pandas, matplotlib, PyQt, and a number of other packages with multiple binary bits and pieces all work well for me in my case, which is building and deploying on Windows desktops.